# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a.65872" with UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, utf-16, numberformatexception

We have a client-server setup which uses REST over SSL with certificate authentication.  Recently, we have observed a "get" through our client-server system sometimes decodes numbers passed as strings incorrectly.  If we do a GET in a browser, we receive correctly for example `0.65872`, but on our client it decodes as `a.65872`.  Other examples include:

- `2646` decoded as `l646`
- `0.76135` decoded as `a.76135`
- `150` decoded as `c50`

We first thought is was related to the Java version of the clients, because switching to a known good Java version solved the problem for that client.  Later we experienced the same decoding problem with what we had thought were known good Java versions. We have tried various versions of Java 7 and Java 8.

We then noticed that if we shortened an earlier number in the stream slightly, the problem would go away for that instance.  So we switched from UTF-8 encoding to UTF-16 encoding in our ReST transmissions, and so far the problem has not re-occurred.

What is the cause?

Comment: How do you read from your `InputStream`?

Comment: Excellent question.  We pass XML, and use XOM to read the elements.  We are using XOM 1.2.5, and tried 1.2.6 with no improvement.

Comment: Are these manglings (e.g. `0` -> `a`, `2` -> `l`, `1` -> `c`) consistent?  Or does `0` sometimes map to some other character, and so on?

Comment: numbers are in the ascii "set" encoding should not be an issue

Comment: dimo414: There are no observations which disprove a hypothesis that the mangling is consistent.

Comment: RC: I agree that ascii encoding of numbers should not be an issue, but observations disprove a hypothesis the the ascii set is correctly decoded.

Comment: Please provide code of the server and client, specifically around XML parsing